# How do you disable the thick blue borders in Win32 Office 2013 applications?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, citrix, citrix-receiver

In Office 2013 applications, the system draws a thick blue border around the application that merges with other open Office 2013 applications. While this looks really neat on a proper desktop, it causes a lot of issues for remote users running over Citrix.

Is there a registry key to disable this blue border?

[image]

Comment: That's why I always use RemoteApp...anyway, it's hard-coded. RemoteApp transports it properly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Microsoft has made it [exceptionally clunky](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2821007) to work around, [Citrix Technology Professional](https://www.citrix.com/community/ctp.html), Thomas Kötzing is your friend.

In his words, "Citrix had to fix seamless applications now for over 20 years and build a long list on how to fix different seamless issues".

Fixing the problem under Citrix, requires just two registry settings, as the mechanism for tweaking seamless windows is already in place. Thomas provides a registry file and XML file for Group Policy Preferences, that makes the ugly thick border thin:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Citrix\wfshell\TWI\MSO_BORDEREFFECT_WINDOW_CLASS]
"ClassName"="MSO_BORDEREFFECT_WINDOW_CLASS"
"Type"=dword:00001000
```

More details, including a workaround for RemoteApp, can be found in his article: [How to disable Office 2013 shadow boarder](http://www.thomaskoetzing.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=379&Itemid=254)
[*sic*]

Answer (score 2):

The border color is a hard coded part of the theme you are using in your Office 2013. The "White" theme has a light blue border, "Light Gray" makes it deep blue and "Dark Gray" draws just plain black borders. It cannot be disabled or changed. Sadly.

There is an (unsupported) theme hack[er]: http://officethemehacker.wordpress.com/

Reference:

- [How to Customize Office 2013 Backgrounds & Themes](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-customize-office-2013-backgrounds-themes/)
- [Changing to a theme with color in Office 2013?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ed1de1dc-1389-4980-acf2-aefc95947ac1/changing-to-a-theme-with-color-in-office-2013?forum=officeitpro)